# Angular 5 -- webpack issue

Tags: angular

I have the following setup on a win x-64 machine:

```
_                      _                 ____ _     ___
/ \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
/ △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
/ ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
|___/

Angular CLI: 1.5.5
Node: 9.2.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.0-rc.2
@angular/cli: 1.5.5
@angular/material: 5.0.0-rc.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.34
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.38
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.8
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

I get the following error msg:

```
ERROR in C:/Users/xxx/documents/proj/data-collection/src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\xxx\documents\proj\data-collection\src\main.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\xxx\documents\proj\data-collection\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:643:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\xxx\documents\proj\data-collection\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in C:/Users/xxx/documents/proj/data-collection/src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\xxx\documents\proj\data-collection\src\polyfills.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\xxx\documents\proj\data-collection\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:643:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\xxx\documents\proj\data-collection\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

This probl happens also after a very fresh: `ng new foo`

There's a long thread [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8263) but I nevertheless have not managed to get to the root of the problem. Tried to fudge with the `@ngtools/webpack` versions but this turned out to be a too big combinatoric problem

My `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "data-collection",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.4",
    "common-tags": "^1.5.1",
    "polyfills": "^2.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that it's not a solution, but angular-cli 1.5.3 it's fine. You can uninstall the most recient angular-cli and install the 1.5.3:npm uninstall -g @angular/cli;npm cache verify;npm install -g @angular/cli@1.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ng serve --preserve-symlinks`.

It helps in most cases for current version of Angular.

Check if you run `ng serve` from symbolically linked folder. If you do, run it from the real one.